# Change woocommerce login form in my account page

Tags: forms, woocommerce, elementor

I have a separate login page using Elementor that I can use for Login and Register but it does not replace the default Woocommerce Login/Register Page. How can i replace the default login/Registration form with my custom form on the "my account" page?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default woocommerce templates in the wp-admin, Woocommerce>  Settings > Advanced. Then on "my account" option select the page you want it to be.